# Distinguish between enum and enum class in template

Tags: c++

Is there a way to distinguish between an enum and an enum class when passed as a template parameter.

In my class I need to serialize an enum or an enum class to and from an integer/byte array. Now for the normal enum I do not strictly have to static cast the value back and forth. For the enum class of course I do.*

This is a simplified example of what I could use:

```cpp
tempate<class TYPE>
class X 
{
  public:
    X()
    {
      static_assert(std::is_enum<TYPE>, "Only enum and enum class allowed.");
    }

    TYPE get() 
    {
      // This is the point of interest
      if(std::is_enum_class<TYPE>::value)
      { 
        return static_cast<TYPE>(value);
      }
      else
      {
        return value;
      }
    }

  private:
    int value;
};
```

I am considering whether there is a way to distinguish between the two along the line of std::is_enum?

- Is it even worth bothering? It is a high performance implementation but would the cast of an enum not be almost instantaneous?

Comment: It's fine to just use the `static_cast` in both cases. If an implicit conversion exists, then `static_cast` does the same thing as the implicit conversion.

Comment: @Brian Thanks for your answer, your fast!

Comment: Furthermore, it's not "almost instantaneous", but not really a piece of runtime code at all! I'd expect this to be a no-op at runtime, barring weirdnesses.

Comment: I've dupe-hammered as the actual question you asked, anyway.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thank you for pointing me to the other question it is in deed the same